# I opened my .exe in notepad and found that it contains file locations, is there anyway to obfuscate this?

Tags: c++, compilation, obfuscation

I made a compiled a sample program in C++ Using VS2013 and copied the "Release" into my desktop and changed it to a text file, I opened this text file and although most of the file was gibberish I could not understand, after scrolling down for a long time, I saw the location of my folders, why is this and is there any way to obfuscate it?

Edit:
I am, in fact, referring to the location of the pdb file. And setting the Linker Debugging options to "NO" seemed to do the trick, thanks everyone!

Comment: They refer to debugging information files (usually with the `pdb` extension).

Comment: Where's the harm? Why would you need to obfuscate it?

Comment: If nothing else, you could always open the binary in a hex editor and manually replace the paths with garbage.

Comment: My full name is in my C: drive. It goes C:\Users\MY FULL NAME\. I wouldn't want that shown when I release a program.

Comment: It could also be `assert` macros.

Comment: You could always move your build folder to something generic. of course that could open an entirely new set of problems. I advise you do *not* use the build folder. `c:\\Make Money Fast`

Comment: Show your compile options, and a "brief" sample of the output (with your name obfuscated, of course) please.

Comment: String literals are stored in the executable as... strings. If you *change* those, you change the program! Do you have this path as a string in the application? If so, probably not a good path for any program you are going to give to someone else, since they probably don't have the same name... [Sysinternals Strings v2.52](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897439.aspx)

Comment: @crashmstr: Most likely he's already checked that, and they're debugging information of some sort, not string literals in code.

Comment: You probably see the path to the PDB, helps the debugger to locate it when the executable is moved.  Set the linker's /DEBUG option to No.

Comment: @Drew McGowen: Opening the executable in a hex editor and editing the location of the .pdb file seems to corrupt the executable and give me the error: "This app cannot be run on your PC"

Comment: Based on your previous question, you don't want personally identifying information in the exploit code you write? That's interesting.

Comment: I'm on a mission to hack the NSA and finally reveal that the do, in fact, monitor and hide cake. In all seriousness, the reason I was studying on shellcode was not for any malicious reason, I wanted to learn about it because I did not understand it. I don't like not understanding things. The first time I heard how hackers get into your computer and control it remotely using a buffer-overflow attack, I knew I had to know how it was done to further prevent it from happening to me.

Comment: @Blastfurnace Upon closer review of your comment, you seem to assume that I'm working on shellcoding, I am not. I only wanted to understand how it works. I was just testing out a new compiler and wondered where all this extra information came from.

Comment: I should have used a smiley, I didn't mean to accuse you of nefarious activity. Many exploits and security holes are surprisingly simple. Of course the simple ones are becoming less successful as programmers pay more attention to security issues. Good luck with your research.